# How to define custom synonyms list in lucene synonymmap

Tags: search, lucene

I want to define synonym words related to a particular domain in Lucene 8*. I have a list of synonyms in CSV format. I didn't see any sample code of example for this. I only saw example for older version which doesn't work now.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example of using synonyms in Lucene 8 (tested using 8.7.0).

Here is an example analyzer:

```java
boolean ignoreSynonymCase = Boolean.TRUE;

Analyzer analyzer = new Analyzer() {
    @Override
    protected Analyzer.TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName) {
        Tokenizer source = new StandardTokenizer();
        TokenStream tokenStream = source;
        tokenStream = new LowerCaseFilter(tokenStream);
        tokenStream = new ASCIIFoldingFilter(tokenStream);
        tokenStream = new SynonymGraphFilter(tokenStream, getSynonyms(), ignoreSynonymCase);
        tokenStream = new FlattenGraphFilter(tokenStream);
        return new Analyzer.TokenStreamComponents(source, tokenStream);
    }
};
```

It uses a [`SynonymGraphFilter`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_7_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/synonym/SynonymGraphFilter.html) to handle your synonyms, which need to be added to a [`SynonymMap`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_7_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/synonym/SynonymMap.html) (see below for that).

Note the use of `FlattenGraphFilter` in the above example - which is needed during indexing as described in the synonym filter javadoc:

> *However, if you use this during indexing, you must follow it with FlattenGraphFilter to squash tokens on top of one another like SynonymFilter, because the indexer can't directly consume a graph.*

My `getSynonyms()` method is as follows:

```java
private static SynonymMap getSynonyms() {
    // de-duplicate rules when loading:
    boolean dedup = Boolean.TRUE;
    // include original word in index:
    boolean includeOrig = Boolean.TRUE;

    SynonymMap.Builder builder = new SynonymMap.Builder(dedup);

    // examples of single synonyms:
    builder.add(new CharsRef("can't"), new CharsRef("cannot"), includeOrig);
    builder.add(new CharsRef("what's"), new CharsRef("what is"), includeOrig);

    // example with multiple synonyms:
    CharsRefBuilder multiWordCharsRef = new CharsRefBuilder();
    SynonymMap.Builder.join(new String[]{"do not", "does not"}, multiWordCharsRef);
    builder.add(new CharsRef("don't"), multiWordCharsRef.get(), includeOrig);

    SynonymMap synonymMap = null;
    try {
        synonymMap = builder.build();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.print(ex);
    }
    return synonymMap;
}
```

So, for example, it treats `cannot` as a synonym for `can't`. And you can therefore search for `cannot` successfully in a phrase such as `This can't be done!`.

How you load your synonyms from your source CSV file is up to you - for example, you can call `builder.add()` in a loop.

Comment: It worked thanks but the sequence in which we add CharsRef in builder also matters. So I need to add all combinations in order for it to work.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Is something preventing you from adding all combinations, in the required order?

Comment: What I mean was if I add builder.add(new CharsRef("can't"), new CharsRef("cannot"), includeOrig); during indexing time and search for "can't" it doesnt search for  "cannot". I have to add "builder.add(new CharsRef("cannot"),  new CharsRef("can't") , includeOrig);" as well. No, there is nothing stopping me from adding all the combinations. I just wanted to know if my understanding is correct or I am doing something wrong here.