# Multiple synonym matching is not working the way I intend or expect, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: lucene

I am indexing technical documentation and incorporating synonyms at index time, so that users can search with a number of alternative patterns. But only some synonyms seem to be getting into the map.
I have a text file `synonyms.list` which contains a series of lines like so:

```
note,notes,notice
subtree,sub-tree,sub tree
```

My analyzer and synonym map builder (I've removed try and catch wrappers to save space, but they aren't the problem):

```
public class TechAnalyzer extends Analyzer {
@Override
protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName) {
  WhitespaceTokenizer src = new WhitespaceTokenizer();
  TokenStream result = new TechTokenFilter(new LowerCaseFilter(src));
  result = new SynopnymGraphFilter(result, getSynonyms(getSynonymsList()), Boolean.TRUE);
  result = new FlattenGraphFilter(result);
  return new TokenStreamComponents(src, result);
}
private static SynonymMap getSynonyms(String synlist) {
  boolean dedup = Boolean.TRUE;
  SynonymMap synMap = null;
  SynonymMap.Builder builder = new SynonymMap.Builder(dedup);
  int cnt = 0;
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(synlist));
  String line;
  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    processLine(builder,line);
    cnt++;
  }
  br.close();
  if (cnt > 0) {
    synMap = builder.build();
  }
  return synMap;
}
private static void processLine(SynonymMap.Builder builder, String line) {
  boolean keepOrig = Boolean.TRUE;
  String terms[] = line.split(",");
  if (terms.length > 1) {
    String word = terms[0];
    String[] synonymsOfWord = Arrays.copyOfRange(terms, 1, terms.length);
    for (String syn : synonymsOfWord) {
      addPair(builder, word, syn, keepOrig);
    }
  }
}
private static void addPair(SynonymMap.Builder builder, String word, String syn, boolean keepOrig) {
  CharsRef synp = SynonymMap.Builder.join(syn.split("\\s+"), new CharsRefBuilder());
  CharsRef wordp = new CharsRef(word);
  builder.add(wordp, synp, keepOrig);
  // builder.add(synp, wordp, keepOrig); // ? do I need this??
}
```

I'm not splitting `word` in `addPair()` because (at the moment, anyway) the first term in every line of `synonyms.list` must be a word not a phrase.

My first question relates to that comment at the bottom of `addPair()`: if I am adding `(word,synonym)` to the map, do I also need to add `(synonym,word)`? Or is the map commutative? I can't tell, because of the problem I'm having which is the basis of the next question.

So... the technical documentation being indexed contains some documents which refer to "release notes", and some which refer to "release notices". There are also points described as a "release note". So I would like a search for any of "release note", "release notes", or "release notice" to match all three alternatives.

My code doesn't seem to enable this. If I index a single file which refers to "release notes" I can inspect the generated index with **luke** and I can see that the index only ever contains one synonym, not two. The same position in the index might have "note" and "notes", or "notes" and "notice", depending on the order of the words in the `synonyms.list` text file, but it will never have "note", "notes" and "notice".

Obviously I'm not building the map correctly, but the documentation hasn't helped me see what I am doing wrong.

If you've read this far, and can see the flaw in my code, please help me see it too!

Thanks, etc.

Comment: For the 1st part of the question "_is the map commutative?_" - For your indexed synonyms, no. If you have the word `foo` with synonyms `bar` and `baz`, then a search for `foo` will find documents containing `foo` but not the synonyms. But a search for `bar` will find documents containing `bar` and also documents containing the word for which `bar` is a synonym (`foo`) - but not `baz`. I expect (but have not tested) that the same would be true for synonyms defined at search-time.

Comment: So this means that, e.g. if I want note,notes,notice to match each other, I need to permute the list and add "note: notes,notice"; "notes: note,notice"; "notice: note,notes"? If that's the case I still have the problem that I'm only getting one synonym per word. My guess is that this might be because I'm adding them in pairs, and only the last word,synonym pair for each "word" is working.

Comment: I see your point now (sorry, missed it the first time around). If you want each word to be a synonym of the other words, you can use the syntax which provides an array of synonyms for each word (and, yes, you would have to cycle through 3 of these if you have 1 word + 2 synonyms). Syntax example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65075353/12567365). And yes, I have not tested it, but I believe you cannot achieve this by just iterating over "1 synonym for 1 word" permutations.

Comment: OK, thanks. Your first comment mentioned "synonyms defined at search time". I read (somewhere, can't find the link) that the recommended approach is to add synonyms to the index, and not to complicate the search by introducing synonyms there as well. But I'm still feeling my way here, and might have misunderstood.

Comment: You understood correctly. And I agree with what you say.

Comment: Hopefully the last question: in my example 'subtree,sub-tree,sub tree' I  add 'sub tree' to the map after splitting the words and 'join'ing them (which I believe swaps the spaces for WORD_SEPARATORs). The source you show in the link you gave (very helpful thank you!) retains the spaces. Does this matter? What difference does it make?

Comment: Where I'm at: note/notes/notice is working, sort of. I can see from **luke** that the phrase "release note x" now generates term "release" at position 0, "note" at position 1, "notes" at position 1, "notice" at position 2, and "x" at position 3. As it happens this is OK, because my application doesn't reply on the exact positions, just on whether a term matches or not.
But I am still having a problem with  phrase synonyms, which I'll raise separately (it's not really the topic of this post).